# VBA read and store data

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2.
On Sheet1 A1:A30 there is a list of numbers.
[image]
On Sheet2, the user needs to input a number on cell A2.
What can I use to make a code that if the number of Sheet2 A2 matches that of Sheet1 A column, it does the action of copying the content of Sheet2 B2 cell into the B cloumn of Sheet1 that matches the number?
For example, if the user input is 130 on Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet1 should be like this:

[image]

still learning VBA and I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: What is your motivation for using VBA instead of cell formulas? Is your problem just a small part of a bigger data operation or are you just attempting to solve this problem for educational purposes? I'm asking because a solution using just cell formulas would be much simpler than any VBA solution.

Comment: Hey! Yes, it was indeed part of a bigger operation and also for educational purposes. I needed a loop but didn't know how it works on VBA, I thought it would need to increment a variable by 1 inside the loop in order get the matching row on sheet1, turns out that the offset thing is much simpler.

Comment: Understood. There is also the option to combine both approaches: you can use VBA to write formulas to cells. Sometimes this is helpful for verifying that an excel solution is working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this code:

1. Press `ALT + F11` to open the VBA editor in Excel.
2. Insert a new module by right-clicking on any existing module or the workbook name on the left > Insert > Module.
3. Paste the below code into the module.
4. Close the VBA editor.
5. Run the macro by pressing `ALT + F8`, selecting `CopyDataBasedOnMatch`, and clicking "Run".

Every time you run this macro, it will check the value in `Sheet2!A2` and perform the described action if a match is found in `Sheet1!A1:A30`.

To check if the value in `Sheet2!A2` matches any value in the range `Sheet1!A1:A30`.
If a match is found, copy the value from `Sheet2!B2` to the corresponding row in `Sheet1` column B.

Here's a VBA macro that accomplishes this:

```vb
Sub CopyDataBasedOnMatch()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim matchValue As Variant, copyValue As Variant

    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ' Get the value to match and the value to copy
    matchValue = ws2.Range("A2").Value
    copyValue = ws2.Range("B2").Value

    ' Loop through each cell in the range A1:A30 of Sheet1
    For Each cell In ws1.Range("A1:A30")
        If cell.Value = matchValue Then
            ' If a match is found, copy the value from Sheet2!B2 to the corresponding row in Sheet1 column B
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = copyValue
            Exit For ' Exit the loop once a match is found
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```